# angular: accessing a JSON value using a variable key

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a variable `param` in scope as `$scope.param` that is always either `foo` or `bar`. I'm creating a table with rows defined by `<tr ng-repeat="d in data">`.

When I have the following: `<td>{{d.foo}}</td>` or `<td>{{d.bar}}</td>` everything works and the data shows up fine. However, when I have `<td>{{d.param}}</td>` angular can't find anything and the cell is blank.

In other words, I'm trying to access an object value using a variable as the key rather than the key itself. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: $scope.param and @scope.data are not the same thing. Just put param and not d.param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bracket notation:

```
{{d[param]}}
```